# Using parameters in open query statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to use sql parameters in below sql open query statement. But it was getting me error for incorrect syntax. I'm not familiar how to use single quotes  for parameters.

```
select * from openquery(MYSQL_FIS,'
SELECT 
CASE WHEN CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID = ''abc'' THEN ''abcd'' ELSE CASE WHEN PARTICIPANT = 1 THEN ''Market'' ELSE ''Customers'' END END as AccountNo,
''Investment'' Account_Name,
cast(SUM(FACEVALUE)as decimal(38,6)) Amount
FROM DEAL, CUSTOMER 
WHERE DEAL.DEALTYPECODE IN (''R'')
AND DEAL.CUSTOMERID = CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID AND DEAL.SUBACCOUNTID = CUSTOMER.SUBACCOUNTID
AND MATURITYDATE >= date_add(''' + @DatePara2 +''' ,Interval 1 Day)
AND STATUS != ''C''
AND STATUS != ''E'' 
AND STATUS != ''T''
AND STATUS != ''Q''
AND VALUEDATE < date_add(''' + @DatePara2 + ''',Interval 1 Day)
GROUP BY DEALTYPECODE,
CASE WHEN CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID = ''C'' THEN ''C'' ELSE CASE WHEN PARTICIPANT = 1 THEN ''Market Participant'' ELSE ''Customers'' END END
)) FIS
group by AccountNo)
```

Comment: You are *NOT* using parameters in this query. You are concatenating strings, which probably results in an invalid query string. Since OPENQUERY *doesn't* accept parameters, at least create the query and store it in a separate variable in order to inspect it.

Comment: `OPENQUERY` only accepts a *value* for it's second argument. Not an *expression*, not a *variable*. Which means you now need to make this outer query dynamic too. Lots of fun getting escaping right. Stop and consider whether this is the right approach.

Comment: that mean am I unable to use parameters in Open query

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever indeed, I've had this fun before querying Active Directory in a statement. In this case, looks like an avoidable hassle. A simpler, more maintainable, more efficient alternative is available.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
select * from openquery(MYSQL_FIS,'
SELECT 
CASE WHEN CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID = ''C'' THEN ''C'' ELSE CASE WHEN PARTICIPANT = 1 THEN ''Market'' ELSE ''Customers'' END END as AccountNo,
''Investment in Repo Agreement'' Account_Name,
cast(SUM(FACEVALUE)as decimal(38,6)) Amount
FROM DEAL, CUSTOMER 
WHERE DEAL.DEALTYPECODE IN (''R'')
AND DEAL.CUSTOMERID = CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID AND DEAL.SUBACCOUNTID = CUSTOMER.SUBACCOUNTID
AND MATURITYDATE >= date_add(''' + @DatePara2 +''' ,Interval 1 Day)
AND STATUS != ''C''
AND STATUS != ''E'' 
AND STATUS != ''T''
AND STATUS != ''Q''
AND VALUEDATE < date_add(''' + @DatePara2 + ''',Interval 1 Day)
GROUP BY DEALTYPECODE,
CASE WHEN CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID = ''C'' THEN ''C'' ELSE CASE WHEN PARTICIPANT = 1 THEN ''Market Participant'' ELSE ''Customers'' END END
)) FIS
group by AccountNo')
```

Comment: Please try to put more *information* into your answer. *What have you changed* and why will/should it fix the OP's problem? The point of this site is to have useful answers that don't just serve the original question asker.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Microsoft official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) 'OPENQUERY does not accept variables for its arguments.' This means you can also not concatenate inside the function - I guess it won't parse anything after the first closing quote.

You need to use the whole statement in [EXEC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to get it working:

```
EXEC ('select * from openquery(MYSQL_FIS,''...

')
```

and you need to double the quotes everywhere inside openquery because the whole thing needs to be between quotes inside EXEC and you need to escape all again (notice the inital 2 single quotes I put to start the query string after the linked server name), so e.g.

```
CASE WHEN CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID = ''CC00001'' THEN ''CBSL''
```

should become

```
CASE WHEN CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID = ''''CC00001'''' THEN ''''CBSL''''
```